# What will be output and exact operation of #

Tags: c

Will this code should recognizable # token,
When I run this code on different compiler, it is giving different output. Why?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#define foo(a,b) #b
int main(void) {
    int a=10,b=15,ab=20;
    // your code goes here
    printf("%d",ab+foo(a,b));
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: c macroses define `#` and `##` operations

Answer (score 2):

The C preprocessor does use `#` as an operator. It's a stringification operator.

Your macro will take whatever token `b` is, and turn it to a string literal. A top of my head simple use for it, is debugging:

```
#define print_int(a) printf(#a " = %d", a);
```

But your program just exhibits undefined behavior. Let's expand the macro:

```
printf("%d",ab+"b");
```

You take an integer (20), and use it for pointer arithmetic against a string literal. Way past the end of the literal in fact, thus getting undefined behavior.

Comment: `ab` has a value `20`, not `150`.   And it is being added to a pointer, not used as an index.

Comment: @Peter - Answering late makes one think `ab` is `a*b`. Corrected, thank you.